# Tkinter Menu Will Not Show

Tags: python, tkinter

Why is the file_menu not showing when I click on the file_button?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def dummy_command():
    print("This is a placeholder command.")

# Window
window = Tk()
window.configure(bg="#1f1f1f")

# Title bar
title_bar = Frame(window, bg="#181818")
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('logo design.png').resize((20, 20)))
label = Label(title_bar, image=logo, bg="#181818")
label.pack(side=LEFT)
title_bar.pack(anchor=N, fill=X)

# File Menu
file_menu = Menu(window)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=dummy_command)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=dummy_command)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=window.destroy)

# File Menu Button
file_button = Menubutton(title_bar, text="File", bg="#181818", fg="white", indicatoron=0)
file_button.pack(side='left')
file_button["menu"] = file_menu  # Set the menu for the Menubutton

# Main loop
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create `file_menu` as child of `file_button`:

```py
# File Menu Button
file_button = Menubutton(title_bar, text="File", bg="#181818", fg="white", indicatoron=0)
file_button.pack(side='left')

# File Menu
file_menu = Menu(file_button) # create as child of file_button
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=dummy_command)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=dummy_command)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=window.destroy)
file_button["menu"] = file_menu  # Set the menu for the Menubutton
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do. You don't need to create a menu separately and link to menu button. Explanation given as comments

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def dummy_command():
    print("This is a placeholder command.")

# Window
window = Tk()
window.configure(bg="#1f1f1f")

#added geometry
window.geometry('300x200')

# Title bar
title_bar = Frame(window, bg="#181818")

#replaced space in filename with undescore to avoid complications of escaping space each time (in bash script). 
#So, Rename the logo by replacing space to underscore
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('logo_design.png').resize((20, 20)))
label = Label(title_bar, image=logo, bg="#181818")
label.pack(side=LEFT)
title_bar.pack(anchor=N, fill=X)

# File Menu

file_button = Menubutton(title_bar, text="File", bg="#181818", fg="white", indicatoron=0)
file_button.menu = Menu(file_button)
file_button["menu"] = file_button.menu

#create three intvar
'''As Rutchy asked abt IntVar in comment, I'm explaining here.
tkinter takes user input through entries, buttons etc., So the 
user input is stored as separate variables. So classes like 
StringVar, IntVar is used for this. User input for button is 
integer(0 or 1 instead of boolen). So, it is stored in IntVar.If 
it is Entry, as the user input will be string, it should be 
stored in Stringvar(). If you want to set a default user input, 
It can be set with IntVar.set(<Value>) or Stringvar.set(<Value>). 
The user input of the respective widget can be got by 
IntVar.get() or Stringvar.get()
'''
var1 = IntVar() 
var2 = IntVar() 
var3 = IntVar() 

#create menu as check buttons and store to the variable created
file_button.menu.add_checkbutton(label = "Open", variable = var1, command=dummy_command)
file_button.menu.add_checkbutton(label = "Save", variable = var2, command=dummy_command)
file_button.menu.add_separator()
file_button.menu.add_checkbutton(label = "Exit", variable = var3, command=window.destroy)
file_button.pack(side='left')



# Main loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're an absolute legend. May I ask, what are the things under #create 3 var?

Comment: @Rutchy, I've edited mu answer to clarify the doubt you asked. There is no legendary involved. Anybody can learn by practice over a period of time. If it is really helpful, An upvote to my answer will energize me more.